# Laravel, cant' get property of colletion

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have Collection form my Form obj, and iam trying to get all pages belongs to that form,
 when I do `$survey = Forms::find(68)->with('pages')->get();` Iam getting this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#522 ▼
  #items: array:18 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Forms {#562 ▼
      #table: "forms"
      #fillable: array:4 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:9 [▶]
      #original: array:9 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "pages" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#596 ▼
          #items: array:5 [▼
            0 => App\Models\Pages {#628 ▶}
            1 => App\Models\Pages {#632 ▶}
            2 => App\Models\Pages {#633 ▶}
            3 => App\Models\Pages {#634 ▶}
            4 => App\Models\Pages {#635 ▶}
          ]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
   ]
}
```

but can't get property of relations, when I do $form->pages Iam getting null
Its works fine for other property like questions (same relations)

here is my model:

```
class Forms extends Model
{
    protected $table = "forms";
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'description', 'status', 'token');


    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Pages');
    }
   public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Question');
    }
}

class Pages extends Model
{
    protected $table = "pages";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'description' ,'priority', 'token');

    public function form()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Forms');
    }

}
```

and finally, method where Iam trying to get results:

```
   public function index()
    {

        $survey = Forms::with('pages')->find(68);//Did update regarding to sugestion

        dd($survey);


        return view("pages.surveys", compact('survey'));
    }
```

Thanks for any help.
Greg

Comment: Where did you call $forms->pages ?

Comment: I replace dd($survey); to dd($survey->pages); and getting null , othervise getting what's above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems almost of your codes are okay. This might be a problem only with your foreign key. In your pages relationship in your forms, laravel will expect a foreign key in your pages table namely 'form_id' or 'forms_id' since you are not passing a second argument in your pages relationship. Make sure that in your pages migration  your foreign key is set to to form_id also

Comment: table pages use foreign key as "forms_id"

Comment: thank you that was the issue, I had to change method name or add foreign key name value

Answer (score 2):

I think you should reverse the order of the `with()` and `find()` functions.

```
$survey = Forms::with('pages')->find(68);
```

Note that `find()` actually executes the query, therefore you don't have to use `get()` again. As a rule of thumb: if you need to get only one result out of your query you should use `first()` or `find()` (the latter could also be used to retrieve collections), otherwise use `all()` or `get()` to fetch a collection of results.

Comment: still getting null

Comment: You wrote you are using `$form->pages` to get the results, but your variable has been named `$survey`, is that a typo in the question or did you mistakenly type the wrong variable names?

Comment: thats typo, when I do dd($survey);

Comment: Can you update the question with a bit more code where you fetch the result and you try to access the property?

Comment: please see below

Comment: Don't post answers to provide more details about your question, you can edit the original question and put more content in it if you need to. Regarding your issue, can you provide the controller code or the method where you are trying to retrive the form pages?

Answer (score 1):

```
$form = Forms::find(68);
dd($form->pages);
```

OR

```
$form = Form::find(68)->pages->get(); //It will return all the pages having relation
```

try this, It will first find form having id '68' then as per relation given it will fetch the records

Comment: Call to a member function get() on null

Comment: should be Form::find(68)->pages()->get();

Answer (score 0):

when i do dd($survey);

```
   App\Models\Forms {#513 ▼
  #table: "forms"
  #fillable: array:4 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "pages" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#521 ▼
      #items: array:6 [▼
        0 => App\Models\Pages {#552 ▼
          #table: "pages"
          +timestamps: false
          #fillable: array:4 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:6 [▶]
          #original: array:6 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
        1 => App\Models\Pages {#553 ▶}
        2 => App\Models\Pages {#554 ▶}
        3 => App\Models\Pages {#555 ▶}
        4 => App\Models\Pages {#556 ▶}
        5 => App\Models\Pages {#557 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Comment: so eloquent get relation right (Iam able to see it) but when i do $survey->pages , Iam getting null

Comment: Try this one $form = Form::find(68)->pages;

Comment: getting null, ist onlly works when i do Form::find(68)->pages()->get();

Comment: why I can't get property if its listed on output for dd($survey) when I used '->with' method ?\

Comment: the reason why i don't want to use above is that I want to get more than one form (find by specific id is just a test) so if I would like to count pages for specific form I need to do many queries (for each loop)

Comment: If you only need to count the number of pages for each form you could as well do:
`$survey = Forms::withCount('pages')->get()`. Each result should then have a `pages_count` property that you should be able to access in a loop

Comment: thx , that will help, but still wondering why I can't access $survey->pages. Alos I might need to get more info about each page too